# How to provide internationalization properly using Gatsby + Netlify CMS

Tags: gatsby, netlify, netlify-cms

I'm trying to make a multi-language site and faced some problems.

Expected behavior:

1. Language automatically changes depends on browser language
2. The user can switch language

   example: https://tic-tac-toe-ai.surge.sh/

I saw `gatsby-plugin-i18n`and followed the recommendations how to use it, but my problem is I create pages automatically via Netlify CMS and can't get a proper file name, as needed: `page.lang.md`
I'm getting `page-lang.md`.

I was wondering if anyone got a working approach already, or can tell me what am I doing wrong and maybe `gatsby-plugin-i18n` doesn't fit this stack at all

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It’s been a while ago when I was last working on it.

Seems like this topic is more-less still getting people interested, so I decided to share the approach I used to make an internationalization possible with Netlify CMS and Gatsby.

The Advantages:

- The implementation is really simple and doesn’t require any packages ‍♀️
- The maintenance is really easy

But If you already have the working Gatsby/Netlify CMS project and want to add languages it be required to change a structure.

It’s really clean and easy especially when on creating a page in the specific language different people work on.

In my case I have only EN and DE. And two content managers for each language.

Since I need to create a pages in English and German only via CMS I simply created 2 collections in `config.yml`

```
#Blog-Post EN       
  - name: "blogEn"
    label: "Blog (english)"
    folder: `${your_folder}/blog`
    filter: { field: contentType, value: blog }
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    identifier_field: slug
    fields:
      - {label: Template Key, name: templateKey, widget: hidden, default: templates/blog-post}
      - {label: Slug, name: slug, widget: string}
      - {label: Language, name: language, widget: hidden, default: en }
      - {label: Content Type, name: contentType, widget: hidden, default: blog} 

  #Blog-Post DE       
  - name: "blogDe"
    label: "Blog (deutsch)"
    folder: `${your_folder}/de/blog`
    filter: { field: contentType, value: blog }
    create: true
    slug: "{{slug}}"
    identifier_field: slug
    fields:
      - {label: Template Key, name: templateKey, widget: hidden, default: templates/blog-post}
      - {label: Slug, name: slug, widget: string}
      - {label: Language, name: language, widget: hidden, default: de }
      - {label: Content Type, name: contentType, widget: hidden, default: blog}
```

You might have noticed the collections are pretty much the same, so that means you are also able to create one single collection and replace language’s field widget `hidden` 
with `select` and put two options into it.

The output should be:

ENGLISH

```
---
templateKey: templates/blog-post
slug: my little slugy
language: en
contentType: blog
title: My little Posty
---
```

GERMAN

```
---
templateKey: templates/blog-post
slug: my little slugy
language: de
contentType: blog
title: My little Posty
---
```

Note* the slug of the same page in different languages should be the same as this is a key for our future Switcher (and good for SEO as far as I understand)

From this point gatsby-node should filter the pages by language, sanitize the input string and transform it to a valid slug.

We want these slugs for the pages:

`/my-little-slugy/`

`/de/my-little-slugy/`

And our sanitizing and kebabing looks like:

```
  if (language === 'de') {
    return _.kebabCase(slug).length === 0 ? '/de/' : `/de/${_.kebabCase(slug)}/`
  } else {
    return _.kebabCase(slug).length === 0 ? '/' : `/${_.kebabCase(slug)}/`
  }
```

Don't worry - `Lodash` and `_.kebabCase()` comes with `gatsby-starter-netlify-cms`, so still no additional packages.

The next step is fetching the language filed into your `templates/blog-post.js` along with other data you need 
and passing `language` into the LanguageSwitcher component where gatsby link will redirect you from `/my-little-slugy/` to `/de/my-little-slugy/` and vice versa depends on current language passed in.

I didn’t put the whole logic of the template and Component here because it’s pretty heavy as has a lot of other features. But I hope you’ve got my idea.   If people are still interested I will create an example repository.

Regarding redirection depending on location - as far as I understand it's fine for SEO to use a default language at the start(but I can be wrong), and if user wants to read in German - go and hit Switcher.

---

UPD

Here is the [example repo](https://github.com/ponchique/gatsby-netlify-cms-multilanguage) where I do the same with pages and posts

Here is [demo](https://gatsby-netlify-csm-multilanguage.netlify.app/) where you can see how it works

Here is [a medium post](https://medium.com/@ponchique/dead-simple-internationalization-with-gatsby-netlify-cms-d66dc4ecdac4) where I describe how to do the same with pages

---

Comment: This answer is great, but I would definitely be interested in an example tutorial!

Comment: I mean repository, not tutorial.

Comment: No problem, this quarantine will help me to do this fast. I think so.

Comment: Could you share example how to do the same with pages?

Comment: Yes, I hope today evening I kick off the repo

Comment: Hello guys, I just finished the repo and post which describes how to provide a multilanguage with pages

https://medium.com/@ponchique/dead-simple-internationalization-with-gatsby-netlify-cms-d66dc4ecdac4

Here is the example repo https://github.com/ponchique/gatsby-netlify-cms-multilanguage

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 3):

Since NetlifyCMS currently [lacks direct localization support](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-cms/issues/716) as of this writing, you'll currently have to edit a separate copy of each document with changed content by country.  Once you have that, if you edit them all in separate folders (e.g. you have `/blogposts/en` and `/blogposts/de` - the CMS supports two directories but no automatic forcing of authors to make both versions or update both versions), you could then use netlify's [geo redirects](https://www.netlify.com/docs/redirects/#geoip-and-language-based-redirects) to make sure that someone in Germany gets /blogposts/de/ when they try to visit your blog, and someone in au,uk,ie,us,nz gets the /blogposts/en version of the posts:

`/blogposts/* /blogposts/en/:splat 301! country=au,uk,ie,us,nz
/blogposts/* /blogposts/de/:splat 301! country=de`

This means you can link to the posts as /blogposts/title and visitors will automatically be redirected with an HTTP 301 to the appropriate language.

You should consider having a "default" version for visitors from other nonspecified countries. Those would live in /blogposts/title and be shown with the above configuration ONLY if the visitor is not from ANY of the listed countries.